# Excel placing contents of cell into row if content matches

Tags: javascript, excel, csv

Tried everything but obviously it's not working.

So I have 2,000+ products in a csv file.

Each row is a product, columns are name,sku,url,etc. They are missing their urls. The urls are in a separate file.

I'm trying to add the product url to the product row based on the SKU.

The url contains the SKU of the product, so if SKU is XXXX, urls are https://www.blank.com/folder/XXXX-product-detail.jpg

How can place the correct url in the SKU column for the correct product?

If SKU matches in the url file, place cell into corresponding product cell in url column.

Racking my brain on this one. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Loop through the lines in the URL file, using a regex to extract the SKU from each item (or even `.slice()` if the format is fixed length). For the current one, then loop down through your SKU column in the main file to see if there's a match.

Comment: Thanks, but how is this accomplished? 'Looping through the lines', 'regex', etc?